# HR not responding

Tags: human-resources

So I cleared the background last week and was confirmed start date of February 18th. Since I cleared, I have attempted to contact recruiter twice to confirm location I need to report, and also the time I should be there. There has been no response/call back so far. On the company's online portal it still says I am "hired". However, it's less than 6 days away. Should I be worried that the job will be rescinded? How long should I wait to contact them again?

Edit to add: I have electronically signed that I accept the offer. The official offer letter has a start date of Feb 18th. Also filled out some I-9 info electronically. Just to clarify, the recruiter left me a vmail last Wednesday, pretty much saying you have cleared background and start date will be Feb 18th. Since it was late in the evening when I saw message, I called them back Thursday morning, and left vmail confirming that start date works for me, and if they can confirm the time i need to report and the office location. No call back came, so I tried again Friday evening. Then yesterday (monday), I emailed this HR rep that one of the welcome emails came from, and she pretty much said that the recruiter (who is direct employee of the company) or hiring manager should be contacting you before first day about day 1 logistics. She also provided me my recruiter’s email address. Should I email the recruiter today or see if I hear from them another day or two.

Comment: Did you already sign an employee contract indicating after a passed check you'd start?

Comment: Added more details to my questions since it won’t let me comment here

Comment: "Should I be worried that the job will be rescinded", yes, you should simply GO THERE, walk in to the office, explain to the secretary "Say, I'm starting on Monday - but I have not been able to reach Mr Smith - is he around?"  Simple.

Answer (score 5):

Could be that the recruiter is gone on holidays or is out sick. I would try calling the company directly rather than the recruiter themselves.

Without any other information, I'd show up at the location provided by the call at 9am and figure it out after that.

Comment: My recruiter works at the company. I have added some more details to my post as it won’t let me post it in comments

Answer (score 1):

You have been hired (congratulations).

You've left messages with the recruiter, and other HR people know about you.  If anyone contacts you prior to your start date, follow their instructions.

If not, just show up at the main office at "normal start of business time" (typically 8:00 am in the US) and sort it out there.  Ask the receptionist to call either the recruiter, your new boss, or anyone in HR.

This is not a major problem, just a small hiccup in their day-to-day operations.

**Don't sweat the small stuff**